# Java: flatten a list of lists OR objects, preserving class

Tags: java, list, generics, nested-lists, flatten

I'd like to write a method `flatten()` in a class `FunctionalList<E> implements List<E>`. Actually flattening the list isn't the issue, however; I need to preserve the deepest contained class of the original list.

I'm assuming the original list contains elements such that there is some class `<T>` such that every element of the flattened list of of type `T`. I'd like the method to return `FunctionalList<T>`. However, I cannot think of a way to obtain this class, a problem made especially difficult since I'm working with generics.

I've written a simple recursive algorithm to flatten the list:

```
public <T> FunctionalList<T> flatten(){
    FunctionalList<T> l = new FunctionalList<T>();
    for(E e : this){
        if(e instanceof FunctionalList)
            l.addAll(((FunctionalList<?>)e).flatten());
        else
            l.add((T)e);
    }
    return l;
}
```

But it looks like this always returns `FunctionalList<Object>`, which is not ideal. Is there any way to, for example, flatten `[1, 2, [3, 4, 5, [6], 7], [8, 9], 10]` to `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]` WHILE storing the result as `List<Integer>` (or similar)?

Comment: `FunctionalList` should be generic, not only the method in this case.

Comment: So E is a superclass of T and you try to find that most specialized T? Or would it just be as simple as reusing E also in the method, not declaring it again of course?

Comment: @Sebastian E in this case would most likely be Object, as that's the only way I know of to encompass both T and List<T>.

Answer (score 0):

I've come up with a solution... of sorts.

Create an interface `Listable<E>` which acts as a contract that the implementing class is either `E` or `List<E>`. That is, `FunctionalList<E> implements Listable<E>`. Then write the method:

```
public static <L extends Listable<L>> FunctionalList<L> flatten(FunctionalList<? extends Listable<L>> l){
    FunctionalList<L> r = new FunctionalList<L>();
    for(Listable<L> e : l){
        if(e instanceof FunctionalList)
            r.addAll(flatten((FunctionalList<? extends Listable<L>>)e));
        else
            r.add((L)e);
    }
    return r;
}
```

Finally, create some class to be contained by the flattened list which implements Listable, e.g. `public class MyInteger implements Listable<MyInteger>`. The static flatten method now returns `FunctionalList<MyInteger>` as desired.

This is somewhat limiting, however, as the method now only works with elements which implement the interface `Listable`. I'm wondering if there's some more general solution.